# Setting a generic delegate to a class-level variable

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0, delegates

I bumped into an additional question that I needed in regards to this: [Using an IEnumerable<T> as a delegate return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099729/using-an-ienumerablet-as-a-delegate-return-type)

From the above solution, the following was suggested:

```
class Example
{
    //the delegate declaration
    public delegate IEnumerable<T> GetGridDataSource<T>();

    //the generic method used to call the method
    public void someMethod<T>(GetGridDataSource<T> method)
    {
        method();
    }

    //a method to pass to "someMethod<T>"
    private IEnumerable<string> methodBeingCalled()
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
    }

    //our main program look
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //create a new instance of our example
        var myObject = new Example();
        //invoke the method passing the method
        myObject.someMethod<string>(myObject.methodBeingCalled);
    }
}
```

Notice that in someMethod, the delegate "method()" is called. Is there anyway to set a class-level delegate that is called later on?

I.e:

```
 class Example {
    //the delegate declaration
    public delegate IEnumerable<T> GetGridDataSource<T>();

    //this fails because T is never provided
    private GetGridDataSource<T> getDS;

    //the generic method used to call the method
    public void someMethod<T>(GetGridDataSource<T> method)
    {
        getDS = method;
    }

    public void anotherMethod() {
        getDS();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you are trying to achieve and where you have flexibility in your design, there are a number of options. I've tried to cover the ones that I feel most probably relate to what you want to do.

#### Multiple values of T in a single instance of a non-generic class

This is basically what you seem to want. However, because of the generic nature of the method call, you'll need a class level variable that can support any possible value of `T`, and you will need to know `T` when you store a value for the delegate.

Therefore, you can either use a `Dictionary<Type, object>` or you could use a nested type that encapsulates the class-level variable and the method, and then use a `List<WrapperType<T>>` instead.

You would then need to look up the appropriate delegate based on the required type.

```
class Example {
    //the delegate declaration
    public delegate IEnumerable<T> GetGridDataSource<T>();

    //this works because T is provided
    private Dictionary<Type, object> getDSMap;

    //the generic method used to call the method
    public void someMethod<T>(GetGridDataSource<T> method)
    {
        getDSMap[typeof(T)] = method;
    }

    //note, this call needs to know the type of T
    public void anotherMethod<T>() {
        object getDSObj = null;
        if (this.getDSMap.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out getDSObj))
        {
            GetGridDataSource<T> getDS = getDSObj as GetGridDataSource<T>;
            if (getDS != null)
              getDS();
        }
    }
```

#### Single value of T in a single instance of a non-generic class

In this case, you could store the delegate instance in a non-typed delegate and then cast it to the appropriate type when you need it and you know the value of T. Of course, you'd need to know T when you first create the delegate, which negates the need for a generic method or delegate in the first place.

#### Multiple values of T in multiple instances of a generic class

Here you can make your parent class generic and supply T up front. This then makes the example you have work correctly as the type of T is known from the start.

```
class Example<T> {
    //the delegate declaration
    public delegate IEnumerable<T> GetGridDataSource<T>();

    //this works because T is provided
    private GetGridDataSource<T> getDS;

    //the generic method used to call the method
    public void someMethod<T>(GetGridDataSource<T> method)
    {
        getDS = method;
    }

    public void anotherMethod() {
        if (getDS != null)
          getDS();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You either need to make the type generic as well, or use plain `Delegate` and cast back to the right type when you need to invoke it. You can't just use `T` outside a generic context - the compiler will think you're trying to refer to a normal type called `T`.

To put it another way - if you're going to try to use the same type `T` in two different places, you're going to need to know what `T` is somewhere in the type... and if the type isn't generic, where is that information going to live?